# Как в запросе записать where по двум и более столбцам в cursor.query(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Собственно вопрос в заголовке... Требуется проверить содержит ли мой объект (который я заполнил) данные, которые уже есть в таблице, т.к. не знаю ответа на свой вопрос решил его таким способом(но считаю его говнокодом):

```
DirectCursorWrapper c = queryDirects(DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION + "= ?", new String[]{description});
DirectCursorWrapper c2 = queryDirects(DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT + "= ?", new String[]{product});` `  
    if (c.moveToFirst() && c2.moveToFirst()) {
        direct.setQty(direct.getQty() + c.getDirect().getQty());
        ContentValues values = getContentValues(direct); mDatabase.update(DirectTable.NAME, values, DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION + "= ?", new String[]{description});
        Toast.makeText(context,R.string.update, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //mDatabase.update(DirectTable.NAME, values, DirectTable.Cols.UUID + "= ?", new String[]{uuidString});
    else {
        ContentValues add_values = getContentValues(direct);
        mDatabase.insert(DirectTable.NAME, null, add_values);
        Toast.makeText(context,R.string.add_direct, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    c.close();
    c2.close();
    mDatabase.close();
```

Может есть веселее решение, ведь надо чтобы update обновлял только в той строке у которой совпадает условие и с description, и с product

Comment: `DirectCursorWrapper c = queryDirects(DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION + "= ?" AND DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT + "= ?", new String[]{description,product});`

Comment: на место каждого следующего `?` в первой части метода подставится следующий аргумент из массива `String[]` второй части метода. таких знаков вопроса и элементов массива может быть любое количество

Answer (score 2):

Синтаксис задания параметризованных запросов в Android SQLite приблизительно такой же как и в классическом JDBC c `PreparedStatement`, грубо говоря запрос состоит из 2-х частей:

1. Маска условия `where` - без самого слова `where`, вместо реальных значений параметров принято вставлять символ `?`
2. Значения параметров `where` - которые будут подставляться вместо символов `?`

В комментарии приведенном @pavlofff это хорошо видно:

```
 DirectCursorWrapper c = 
     queryDirects(
       DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION + "= ?" AND 
       DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT + "= ?", 
 new String[]{description,product});
```

Значения массива `new String[]{description,product}` - будут вставляться вместо символов `?` в первом аргументе, который как раз читается как:

> фильтровать записи, где значение поля `DirectTable.Cols.DESCRIPTION` **и** `DirectTable.Cols.PRODUCT` равны заданным значениям